# Vue passed prop warning not informative

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nodes

In one of the components, I am passing an < html > element of an iframe as a prop. I want to define the type of prop being passed, however, Vue2 throws me a non-indicative warning in the console: `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "xyz". Expected HTMLHtmlElement, got HTMLHtmlElement...`.

I have tried to suppress it with `required: false`, but it did not work. So far defining the type as `type: undefined` does not prompt the warning, but I bet it's a bad practice. Below is the snippet of prop definition:

```
xyz: {
        type: HTMLHtmlElement,
        'default': null,
        required: false
    }
```

Comment: How do you pass it? and are using Typescript?

Comment: I use Javascript and pass it from the parent through :xyz="xyz".

Comment: And how is `xyz` defined?

Comment: xyz is the content of an iframe, which I get through iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]

Comment: since you're just using js you could do only `type: Object,` and with TS you could do `type:Object as  PropType<HTMLHtmlElement>,`

Comment: it's not forbidden to use type 'null' on type but as @BoussadjraBrahim mentioned best way here is to use *type: Object* and You don't need to wrap *default* in ''

Comment: I already tried that, but it still throws "Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "xyz". Expected Object, got HTMLHtmlElement"...